# Cannot see .net FrameWork 4.5 Features

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, .net-4.5

I am trying host the WCF under On IIS 7+ and wanted to set it up by enabling the .Net 4.5 Framework features available from "Add or remove programs" option from Control Pa[image]nel on Windows 7.

I have installed .Net framework 4.0 and  .Net framework 4.5.1. But I still don't see the option for .Net 4.5 features. Any idea why ?. Find attached the features I see while trying to add/remove programs. I see only .Net framework 3.5

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Operating system maintenance is off-topic for SO. Anyway, you don't need to install .NET 4.5 through Windows Componentes. It's installed separately, which you already did.

Comment: I think you need to look under the IIS node in that UI dialog. Simply install 4.5 from a web installer. What exactly do you want to find under that (theoretical) 4.5 node? WCF is always installed and you simply need to make IIS ready.

Comment: I am trying to enable WCF 4.5

Comment: What do you mean by that? There is no such thing as "WCF 4.5". WCF is part of the .NET Framework. Why don't you reply to what I said and let me know if it helped?

Comment: thanks usr. Your replay helped.